# How translate function from MySQL to Firebird?

Tags: mysql, firebird, firebird-3.0

how how can i transfer this function to firebird

```
create function `candidat`(in_num   decimal(10,2),
                           in_group integer unsigned)   
       returns integer unsigned 
       deterministic   
       language sql 
begin   
   return case in_group when 1 then floor(in_num / 3.0 + 0.99)
                        when 2 then floor(in_num / 3.0 + 0.50)
                               else floor(in_num / 3.0) end; 
end
```

Comment: MySQL create function (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) Look into firebird documentation (create function) https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-psql-funcs.html and search the other statements/functions yourself in the firebird manual.. If you understand MySQL's create function syntax and read the firebird syntax it should be really easy to do it yourself.

Comment: Please show your attempt, and explain what you are stuck on. Except for the differences in the function header, this function should translate almost 1-on-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create Firebird 3 PSQL [function](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-ddl-function), which will be almost identical to the MySQL function. The mayor differences are just the creation syntax:

```
create function candidat(in_num   decimal(10,2),
                         in_group integer)   
       returns integer
as
begin   
   return case in_group when 1 then floor(in_num / 3.0 + 0.99)
                        when 2 then floor(in_num / 3.0 + 0.50)
                               else floor(in_num / 3.0) end; 
end
```

As Firebird doesn't have unsigned integers, you need to use a normal (signed) `integer` instead. Given the input that should be sufficient, otherwise consider switching to `bigint`.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways do extract the data that you whant:

1. Add a CASE in your SQL:

   ```
   select
      case when :in_group = 1 then floor(:in_num / 3.0 + 0.99)
           when :in_group = 2 then floor(:in_num / 3.0 + 0.50)
           else floor(:in_num / 3.0) end
   from
      RDB$DATABASE
   ```

   *OBS: The `RDB$DATABASE` it just a table example de result, and ":in_num" and ":in_group" its a variable/param, that you can change with a column of one table or just inject the value you need*
2. Create a PROCEDURE like:

   ```
   SET TERM ^ ;

   CREATE OR ALTER procedure candidat (in_num decimal(10,2), in_group integer)
      returns ( calculed_value integer )
   as
   begin
     if (:in_group = 1) then
     begin
       calculed_value = floor(:in_num / 3.0 + 0.99);
     end
     else if (:in_group = 2) then
     begin
       calculed_value = floor(:in_num / 3.0 + 0.50);
     end
     else
     begin
       calculed_value = floor(:in_num / 3.0);
     end

     suspend;
   end
   ^

   SET TERM ; ^
   ```

   you can use it like:

   ```
   select 
      CALCULED_VALUE 
   from 
      candidat( 100, 2)
   ```
3. You can create a Library (UDF) using a language like C++ that generate a `.dll` ou `.so` (for linux) with the function `candidat` and than add it to the database.

   For this you can look at the documentation at https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/writing-udfs-for-interbase/

   Then you can use a UDF like:

   ```
   select
     candidat(1,3)
   from
     <TABLE>
   ```

Comment: You missed the Firebird 3 option to create a PSQL function.